# Can i apply the 270Mbps mode on my Netgear CBVG834G or increase frequency range?

Tags: wireless

I have a two floor apartment and my router is downstairs. My reception is lousy on the 1st floor and I am trying to find a solution without having to buy new equipment.
I've tried to change the channels and I didn't notice any difference. I also read about a two channel mode, 'called' 270Mbps mode, which seemed to me a possible solution. Still, I didn't understand how I could do that.
Another thing that I'd like to know if it possible is the frequency range increase, from 2.4GHz to 5Ghz. Maybe there is a way to do it, with this modem, but I haven't found out how, in the modem setup page.
Can anyone help me? 
I apologize in advance if I asked something stupid, but I'm not really acquainted with the subject.

Comment: This literally has nothing to do with Security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post is clearly not in the right forum, but I'll answer it anyway

Unfortunately, your router model does not appear to support the 5Ghz frequency. Thus, you may not be able to increase the frequency of the wireless signal.

Note that in your case, increasing the frequency from 2.4Ghz to 5Ghz may not be a good idea if you want to increase the range of your router's signal. A 5Ghz signal may have more trouble penetrating floors and walls and can have half the range (or less) of the 2.4Ghz frequency.

I suggest you avoid placing your router next to microwaves, computers, or other electronic devices to reduce interference with the 2.4Ghz frequency.

Changing the channel is not effective if you choose another channel that still overlaps with the channels used in your neighborhood. A minimum distance of 6 channels is necessary to avoid overlapping. Therefore, use channel 1 or 11 if the channel 6 is widely used in your neighborhood. Although I doubt it could be a miracle solution in this case...

Comment: @Cátia I believe the one you'll want to look at is [su].